# Dual Contouring - Eliminating sharp edges

Tags: c++, geometry

I want to remove the sharp edges (Cubic looks) of Dual contouring.

It currently looks like this:

[image: SquareShaped]

This is what I get when I try to implement QEF:

[image: Result]

```
 //calculate an error at one edge
 //currentindex is index to the current cube, index1 and index2 each is an index to a cube's corner together form an edge
DirectX::XMVECTOR GeometryGenerator::ReCalcPosition(int CurrentIndex, int index1, int index2, GeometryGenerator::MeshData& meshData)
{
    //get the margin of an intersection point on an edge
    float marg = abs(meshData.Density[index1]) / (abs(meshData.Density[index1]) + abs(meshData.Density[index2]));
    DirectX::XMVECTOR v1 = DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&meshData.Vertices[index1].Position);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR v2 = DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&meshData.Vertices[index2].Position);
    //intersection point on an edge
    DirectX::XMVECTOR IntersectPoint = DirectX::XMVectorAbs(DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(v2, v1));
    IntersectPoint = DirectX::XMVectorScale(IntersectPoint, marg);
    IntersectPoint = DirectX::XMVectorAdd(IntersectPoint, v1);
    //intersection point gradient
    DirectX::XMVECTOR IntersectPointNormal = DirectX::XMVectorSet
    (
        (ImprovedNoise::Noise((double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0] + dv), IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1], IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2]) - ImprovedNoise::Noise((double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0] - dv), IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1], IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2])) / 2,
        (ImprovedNoise::Noise(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0], (double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1] + dw), IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2]) - ImprovedNoise::Noise(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0], (double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1] - dw), IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2])) / 2,
        (ImprovedNoise::Noise(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0], IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1], (double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2] + du)) - ImprovedNoise::Noise(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[0], IntersectPoint.m128_f32[1], (double)(IntersectPoint.m128_f32[2] - du))) / 2,
        0
    );
    IntersectPointNormal = DirectX::XMVector3Normalize(IntersectPointNormal);
    return  qef(DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&meshData.GridVertices[CurrentIndex].Position), IntersectPointNormal, IntersectPoint);
}

DirectX::XMVECTOR GeometryGenerator::qef(DirectX::XMVECTOR vertexPos, DirectX::XMVECTOR normal, DirectX::XMVECTOR intersectionPoint)
{
    DirectX::XMVECTOR subtract = DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(vertexPos, intersectionPoint);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR dot = DirectX::XMVector3Dot(normal, subtract);
    return DirectX::XMVectorPow(dot, DirectX::XMVectorSet(2, 2, 2, 0));
}
```

I iterate over the edges with sign change and sum the error:

```
 error += ReCalcPosition(.....);
```

then get an average and reposition the cube:

```
DirectX::XMVECTOR center = DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&meshData.GridVertices[index].Position);
error = DirectX::XMVectorScale(error, (float)1 / count);
DirectX::XMStoreFloat3(&meshData.GridVertices[index].Position,  DirectX::XMVectorAdd(center, error));// tried subtract didnt work either
```

I want to achieve similar result using DC
[image: smooth].

Here's the code integrated with [Luna Frank sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6c6wgAJlW-v5dJavnd6V-eRfcom_eH4/view?usp=sharing). The main function called CreateCubeGrid in GeometryGenerator.cpp.

Clearly something is wrong in my implementation, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're not clamping the vertex to lie within the cell you're considering.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: [See the section "Problems: Collinear Normals" in this tutorial](https://www.boristhebrave.com/2018/04/15/dual-contouring-tutorial/) for some starting points.